# Developer comments in handlebars with no output in client side

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm using Express Handlebars as a template engine for node.
I know there's an option to add HTML comments with it, but is there a way to add developer comments that won't get printed on the final source ?

This is what I found:

```
{{! This comment will not be in the output }}
<!-- This comment will be in the output -->
```

But looking for:

```
{{! This comment should only be visible in the source file, not in the client side }}
```

Similar to what can be done in PHP in a view:

```
<?php
/* Comment here */
?>
```

Comment: You could use a library to minimize the code removing the comments, or use a preprocessor to have them removed. There is also a npm package for this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-remove-html-comments

Comment: I'm currently using my own helper to remove them, but just wondering if it is possible somehow else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
{{!-- This comment won't get printed in this view --}}
```

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#template-comments

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('comment', function(whatever) {
  return '';
});
```

This way I can do:

```
{{comment 'this field is here to indicate...'}}
<input type="hidden" name="demo" value="4554">
```